# try-catch placement in converting Swift dictionary to JSON string

Tags: swift, try-catch

Here's what I've got:

```
        do {
            try let jsonData: NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(paramsDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
            jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
        } catch {
            print("CAUGHT SOMETHING session token")
        }
```

I'm getting an error `try must be placed on the initial value expression`. I tried 'rephrasing' like so:

```
        do {
            let jsonData: NSData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(paramsDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
            try jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
        } catch {
            print("CAUGHT SOMETHING session token")
        }
```

but this leads to an error `Call can throw but is not marked with 'try'`. How should I be structuring this try-catch and what do these error codes mean?

Answer (score 5):

You have to change the location of where you are putting your `try`.

```
    do {
        if let jsonData: NSData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(paramsDict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted) {
          //is jsonString a variable you have previously declared?
          //if not, put "if let" before it, because you are creating it IF:
          //your "try" - attempt to get data from json succeeds
          jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String 
        }
    } catch {
        print("CAUGHT SOMETHING session token")
    }
```